# Apache Ant + Ivy syntax error

Tags: apache, ant, xml-parsing, dependencies, ivy

I have just setup my first project using apache ant with ivy as dependency manager. It is working great! But I have one thing I cannot get over. Since I have several dependencies that use slf4j there is a conflict with version mismatches. So I defined a conflict tag in the ivy.xml to force a certain version (1.5.6 in this case). Running the Ivy resolve with eclipse plugin IvyIDE works without error. But when using my ant build file to build my application I get a xml syntax error:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Buildfile: B:\core-lib\build.xml
parsing buildfile B:\core-lib\build.xml with URI = file:/B:/core-lib/build.xml
Project base dir set to: B:\core-lib
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/InformDevTools/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/InformDevTools/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `resolve' is [clean, init, resolve]
Complete build sequence is [clean, init, resolve, compile, resources, test, dist, ]
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build\lib
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build\main
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build\report\test
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build\report
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build\test
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\build
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\dist
   [delete] Deleting directory B:\core-lib\dist
init:
Override ignored for property "DSTAMP"
Override ignored for property "TSTAMP"
Override ignored for property "TODAY"
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\build\main
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\build\lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\build\test
    [mkdir] Created dir: B:\core-lib\build\report\test
resolve:
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1992851616/plugins/org.apache.ivy.eclipse.ant_2.3.0.cr120120416000235/ivy.jar!/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1992851616/plugins/org.apache.ivy.eclipse.ant_2.3.0.cr120120416000235/ivy.jar!/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
[ivy:retrieve] No ivy:settings found for the default reference 'ivy.instance'.  A default instance will be used
[ivy:retrieve] Loading jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1992851616/plugins/org.apache.ivy.eclipse.ant_2.3.0.cr120120416000235/ivy.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivy.properties
[ivy:retrieve] searching settings file: trying B:\core-lib\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc1 - 20120416000235 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] jakarta commons httpclient not found: using jdk url handling
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = B:\core-lib\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] no default ivy user dir defined: set to C:\Users\admin\.ivy2
[ivy:retrieve] no default cache defined: set to C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\cache
[ivy:retrieve] settings loaded (31ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  default cache: C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\cache
[ivy:retrieve]  default resolver: inform-artifactory
[ivy:retrieve]  -- 5 resolvers:
[ivy:retrieve]  inform [release] [ibiblio]
[ivy:retrieve]  inform [snapshot] [ibiblio]
[ivy:retrieve]  inform [proxied] [ibiblio]
[ivy:retrieve]  inform-artifactory [chain] [inform [proxied], inform  [third-party], inform [release], inform [snapshot]]
[ivy:retrieve]  inform  [third-party] [ibiblio]
[ivy:retrieve] no resolved descriptor found: launching default resolve
Overriding previous definition of property "ivy.version"
[ivy:retrieve] using ivy parser to parse file:/B:/core-lib/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve] [xml parsing: ivy.xml:28:108: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Ungültiger Content wurde beginnend mit Element "dependency" gefunden. "{conflict}" wird erwartet. in file:/B:/core-lib/ivy.xml
[ivy:retrieve] ]

BUILD FAILED
B:\core-lib\build.xml:77: syntax errors in ivy file: java.text.ParseException: [xml parsing: ivy.xml:28:108: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Ungültiger Content wurde beginnend mit Element "dependency" gefunden. "{conflict}" wird erwartet. in file:/B:/core-lib/ivy.xml
]
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:396)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPostResolveTask.ensureResolved(IvyPostResolveTask.java:231)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPostResolveTask.prepareAndCheck(IvyPostResolveTask.java:178)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyRetrieve.doExecute(IvyRetrieve.java:87)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: [xml parsing: ivy.xml:28:108: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Ungültiger Content wurde beginnend mit Element "dependency" gefunden. "{conflict}" wird erwartet. in file:/B:/core-lib/ivy.xml
]
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser$AbstractParser.checkErrors(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:89)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser$AbstractParser.getModuleDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:344)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(XmlModuleDescriptorParser.java:117)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:184)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:503)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyResolve.doExecute(IvyResolve.java:326)
    ... 20 more

Total time: 500 milliseconds
```

If I remove the conflict definition, the build works as expected. Here is the ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

<info organisation="eu.inform" module="isac3-core" revision="1.0-snapshot"></info>
<configurations>
    <conf name="build" description="provide business logic for isac3"/>
    <conf name="test" extends="build" visibility="private" description="just for JUnit testing"/>
</configurations>
<publications>
    <artifact name="core-lib" type="jar" conf="build" ext="jar"/>
</publications>
<dependencies>

    <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-lang3" rev="3.1" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.6" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.mina" name="mina-core" rev="2.0.4" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.tika" name="tika-app" rev="1.1" conf="build->default"/>
    <!-- 
        Resolve conflict for SLF4J by selecting the latest compatible version:
        Apache tika comes packaged with slf4j 1.5.6, so we cannot exclude this dependency because it is part of the jar.
        Hibernate specifies a dependency to slf4j 1.6.1 by maven pom file.
     -->
    <conflict org="org.slf4j" rev="1.5.6"/>

    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aop" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjweaver" rev="1.5.4" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm" rev="3.1.1.RELEASE" conf="build->default">
        <!-- don't include any ORM implementation since we defined the one we use -->
        <exclude org="org.eclipse.persistence" />
        <exclude org="toplink.essentials" />
        <exclude org="org.apache.ibatis" />
        <exclude org="org.apache.openjpa" />
        <exclude org="org.hibernate" />
    </dependency>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="4.1.4.Final" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-ehcache" rev="4.1.4.Final" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-envers" rev="4.1.4.Final" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-search-engine" rev="4.1.1.Final" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-search-orm" rev="4.1.1.Final" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="c3p0" name="c3p0" rev="0.9.1.2" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="de.jollyday" name="jollyday" rev="0.4.6" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="build->default"/>

    <!-- JDBC drivers -->
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.jtds" name="jtds" rev="1.2.4" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.microsoft" name="sqljdbc4" rev="4.0" conf="build->default"/>
    <dependency org="com.oracle" name="ojdbc6" rev="11.2.0.3" conf="build->default"/>

    <!-- dependencies solely for testing purposes (none-deployed) -->
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10" conf="test->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

And that is the ant build.xml (I left out unnecessary lines to keep it more compact):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

```
<property name="src_base" location="src/main" />
<property name="src" location="${src_base}/java" />
<property name="config" location="${src_base}/config" />
<property name="resource" location="${src_base}/resource" />
<property name="build" location="build" />
<property name="buildSrc" location="${build}/main" />
<property name="lib" location="${build}/lib" />
<property name="dist" location="dist" />

<property name="distName" value="isac3-core-lib" />
<property name="distFileName" value="${distName}-${build.timestamp}.jar" />
<property name="zipFileName" value="${distName}-${build.timestamp}.zip" />

<property name="test.src" location="src/test/java" />
<property name="test.build" location="build/test" />
<property name="test.reports" location="build/report/test" />

<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7" />
<!-- Source-level version number -->
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7" />
<!-- Class-compatibility version number -->
<property name="build.compiler" value="modern" />

...

<!-- ================================= 
      target: init
     ================================= -->
<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp />
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${buildSrc}" />
    <mkdir dir="${lib}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.reports}" />
</target>

<!-- ================================= 
      target: resolve              
     ================================= -->
<target name="resolve" depends="init" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" />
</target>

...
```

The error happens in the ant target 'resolve'. Ivy seems to be loaded an the settings file is also used as expected. But as already mentioned I get that syntax error.

Has anyone seen this before and can give me a hint?

Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your work and I had the same error, but not in German ;)

Anyway, I tried putting the conflict tag at the end and it worked.
so now it looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    ... all dependencies
    <!-- dependencies solely for testing purposes (none-deployed) -->
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10" conf="test->default"/>

    <conflict  org="org.slf4j" rev="1.5.6" />
</dependencies>
```

Another thing, it might be a copy-paste mistake, but you have to make sure ivy.xml file ends with

```
</ivy-module>.
```

Let us know.

Comment: Thank you. I came across this also. Moving the conflict tag to the end of the dependencies block worked. Thank you.